# Apache Drill - Aggregation SUM query gives exponential result

Tags: mongodb, apache, aggregate-functions, apache-drill

When we do aggregated sum query in Drill for mongo storage , the output result is in exponential form .
Is there anywhere can we configure in drill , so that we can get output without exponential form ?

We dont want exponential result.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It would be helpful to know how your query does look like. Also the input data format and the output data form. Please [edit] your question so that people are able to help.

Answer (score 2):

Drill provides two tools that display query results (and so would format numbers): the Drill web UI and the Sqlline command line tool. Are you using one of these? These tools are often used for experimental queries. I'm not aware of any way to customize the display in that UI.

That said, if you use the ODBC or JDBC driver, then numbers are stored in binary format and so any formatting would be done by the tool using the drivers to run queries. The xDBC drivers are more for production use as they handle large result sets better than the UI tools.

Now, a third possibility is that something in the Mongo plugin converts numbers to strings (VARCHAR). In that case, you might be able to cast the string back to a number.

If you can provide a bit more detail on the tool you are using, perhaps we can provide a bit more focused answer.